# Can I hide book marks on the new tab page on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I use my personal computer for work and I frequently have engineers and otherwise professionals connecting to my computer via remote desktop and I don't want them to see my book marks.  This is a pretty reasonable request and I am suprised chrome doesn't have this functionality.  Hiding the bookmarks bar doesn't hide it from the new tab page.  The only solution is to log out of my google account and log back in every time I am done with a job site, which is just plain dumb.  Why are google products so basic and featureless?  What if I don't want the rest of my company to see all my tradingview charts that I save to the book marks bar for ease of access?

Comment: It has that functionality. Please see my answer and feel free to mark as accepted if it helped cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply right click on the bookmarks tab and unselect the Show bookmarks tab.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/1xftyf9

Comment: That does not work on the new tab page.

Comment: @Lupina Interestingly, indeed it does not work. Most probably intended that way.